# Assigning a new value to be printed out from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I try to do is that when I press 'n' in the while loop a new value will be printed out as the next room I enters.

```
#List of the rooms in my ship
room_list = []

#0
room = ['---text--- North.', 1, None, None, None]
room_list.append(room)

#1
room = ['---text--- East.', None, None, 3, None]
room_list.append(room)

#2
room = ['---text--- North, South, East and West.', 1, 2, 3, 4]
room_list.append(room)

#3
room = ['---text--- West.', None, None, None, 4]
room_list.append(room)

#4
room = ['---text--- East.', None, None, 3, None]
room_list.append(room)

#5
room = ['---text--- North, South, East and West.', 1, 2, 3, 4]
room_list.append(room)

#6
room = ['---text--- West.', None, None, None, 4]
room_list.append(room)

#7
room = ['---text--- South', None, 2, None, None]
room_list.append(room)

#Looping and room variable
current_room = 0
done = False

#Loop
while done == False:
    print(room_list[current_room][0])
    choice = input('\nWhere do you want to go? ')
    if choice == 'n':                           #Problem seems to be here
        next_room = room_list[current_room][2]
    if choice == None:
        print('You can not go that way!')
```

I put a comment where the problem is. I do not know how to assign the value after I have chosen 'n' to print out room number  2 in the list. When I run this, it works. But it just goes round and round, it does not change the value to be printed out from the list.

Comment: You don't use `next_room` anywhere so `current_room` never changes. Perhaps `current_room = room_list[current_room][2]`, or updating the current room later in the loop?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to choose which room or try each room in turn?

Comment: I have tryed it, but then I get a Type error in the print section.

Comment: File "test1.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(room_list[current_room][0])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType

Comment: Rob, Yes, I have a skiss of the spaceship and want to link the doors that one can go through. For example, in the hall(#2) I can go to North, South, East and West witch than links to new rooms that I can reach from that location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `room_list[current_room][2]` is an integer indicating a valid room, or if it is `None` and tell the user they can't go that way. If `room_list[current_room][2]` is an integer, update current_room:

```
while done == False:
    print(room_list[current_room][0])
    choice = input('\nWhere do you want to go? ')
    if choice == 'n':  
        if room_list[current_room][1] is not None:
            current_room = room_list[current_room][1]
        else:
            print('You can not go that way!')
```

I changed the index for "north" to be 1, as room 0 has `[description, 1, None, None, None]` and I assume you want the player to be able to go somewhere!

Also, to save yourself a lot of repetitive code you might make a dictionary of directions:

```
directions = {'n':1, 's':2, 'e':3, 'w':4}

while done == False:
    print(room_list[current_room][0])
    choice = input('\nWhere do you want to go? ')
    if choice in directions:  
        if room_list[current_room][directions[choice]] is not None:
            current_room = room_list[current_room][directions[choice]]
        else:
            print('You can not go that way!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
#Loop
while done == False:
    print(room_list[current_room][0])
    choice = input('\nWhere do you want to go? ')
    if int(choice) in room_list[current_room][1:5]:                         
        current_room = int(choice)
    else choice == None:
        print('You can not go that way!')
```

Comment: No worries, you should also have a look at Eric Appelt's answer. It allows the user to type in n, s, e or w. So it is probably the better answer. Alternatively you could always update the last 4 items in the list to be letters (n,s,e,w) rather than 1-4. Would require a slight mod to the code but then it would also allow users to enter n,s,e,w which might make the game a bit easier to use.

Comment: Yeah Im trying to get this to work now, Will look at Eric's code right away.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update `current_room`. Also notice that the result of `input(...)` cannot be None, it is always a string:

```
if choice == 'n':
    next_room = room_list[current_room][2]
    if next_room == None:
        print('You can not go that way!')
    else:
        current_room = next_room
```

Comment: Still the problem remains. File "test1.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(room_list[current_room][0])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType. I can see that people get eyewounds of this post so will see if I may remove it.